# Как добавить конфигурацию в Сlion для склонированного проекта?

Tags: clion

я склонировал проект с Github, но не хватает конфигурации, чтобы исполнять файлы. как её создать/добавить? я пытался **Run -> Edit Configurations**, создаю **CMake Application**, но что мне подставить в **Target** и **Executable**?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Executable` нажать на `[...]` и указать путь к `CmakeLists.txt`. Если файл составлен без ошибок, при запуске (Shift + F10) таргет добавится сам

Comment: Спасибо большое!